# Sending newsletter from a Zend Framework project

Tags: php, zend-framework, cron, newsletter

I have a Zend Framework project using version 1.10.8 with Doctrine 1.2.4.I use Zend_Auth and Zend_Acl where actions are resources. i have added newsletter functionalitiy recently and being wondering how i would play out together.This my first time doing a real newsletter stuff  and  with Zend in addition.

So my first approach would be have a php script to connect to the db get the template, get the name and email of subscriber . parse the template for customization for users and send it. i will be using swiftMailer. so i would set a cron job to call that file for every period.

Now my worries are with the ACL .if the script is outside Zend (ie my project)and hitting a Zend action(url) to perform all the stuffs how would the system authenticate itself (i mean by system the cron running the php file)?

What are the other approach for using ZF. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required resource to access the given url i.e. /newsletter/send would be accessible to all people. It doesn't matter if real people hit the url, as the content of that page would be quite uninteresting =)

The script itself would simply check if there are mails to send and then grab all users from DB, etc. The Newsletter-methology is pretty unreliant on Zend.

You can easily do the templating stuff with Zend and Zend_Mail, too though. This is how i handle E-Mails in Zend:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail('UTF-8');

$mailView = new Zend_View();
$mailView->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/views/email/');
$mailView->assign('title', $this->_report->getTitle());
$mailView->assign('text', $this->_report->getText());

$mail->addTo($user->getEmail(), $user->getFullnameBySurname());
$mail->setBodyHtml($mailView->render('emailregular.phtml')); // /application/views/email/emailregular.phtml
$mail->setBodyText(strip_tags($mailView->render('emailregular.phtml'))); //might not be the cleanest way...

try {
    $mail->send();
    $mail->clearRecipients(); // This clears the addTo() for Zend_Mail as in my script i only have one instance of zend_mail open while looping through several users
    $this->_log->info('Mail out for user ....');
  } catch (Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception $e) {
    $this->_log->error('Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception for User('.$user->getid().') - Mails were not accepted for sending: '.$e->getMessage());
  } catch (Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception $e) {
    $this->_log->error('Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception for User('.$user->getid().') - SMTP Sentmail Error: '.$e->getMessage());
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->_log->error('Unknown Exception for User('.$user->getid().') - SMTP Sentmail Error: '.$e->getMessage());
  }
```

Hope this is what youre asking for =)

Comment: Thanks very much mate.exactly what am worrying about